# map big json object to model object in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have array of object, each object contains;

```
{
 Id:"..",
 name:"..",
 foo1:"..",
 foo2:"..",
 ...
}
```

I need only 2 properties of these items so I have created an interface;

```
export interface IMenuModel{
    Id:number;
    name?:string;    
}
```

and retrieve data within this method below:

```
 fetch(`..`).then((response: Response): Promise<{ value:IMenuModel[] }>  => {
                  return response.json();
                })
                 .then((response: { value: IMenuModel[] }): void => {
                   debugger //expected response is array of IMenuModel but it still contains all properties
```

I expect this response object as array of my custom model(IMenuModel) but it still contains all properties retrieved from remote source.

I can pluck them with ".map()" function thats ok but there is return type defined to function(`response: { value: IMenuModel[] }`) so I shouldnt have to do this(or do I have to map it manually each time).

Why still response not in my object model and  whats the most efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is mostly a type layer on top of JavaScript. These typings do not change the typed object. When transpiled into JavaScript the typings are simply dropped. If you apply an interface (or multiple interfaces) to your JSON object, you don't change the nature of the object, you just declare the guarantees of that interface.

So when you define your `IMenuModel` interface and apply it to your imported object you are saying: *"I know and I can guarantee that the given object provides the members defined in the interface."* This guarantee is satisfied by your object, so everything is fine there. The object however is still transmitted and restored in its full glory. Consider the interfaces as *minimum* guarantees, not as full descriptions of the object.

If you don't want the additional members of the object, your only choice is to let the server send only the parts of the object you need. If you can't do that, you don't need to worry, as your object meets the minimum requirements of the interface. Just ignore the additional values.